# react native testing library getByText in nested component

Tags: reactjs, react-native-testing-library

I have a component with the following structure

```js
<T>
    <T>{" "} Hi</T>
how are you ?
</T>
```

when I do getByText("how are you ?") it doesn't find anything
and I couldn't use custom matcher
Any suggestion ?

Comment: You can use regex in the `getByText()`. eg `getByText(/Hi/i);`. This helps when there is nested Text views. Regex is a good way to match what you want to match in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked :

```
getByText(" Hihow are you ?")
```

seems weird , but worked